# Cannot get model variable to display on page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In my MVC 5 app, I have a page with some HTML at the top of the page that looks as follows:

```
@model Entities.SightingSearch

<div class="page-header">
    <h3 class="text-center">Sightings</h3>
    <h4 class="text-center">@Html.Label(Model.CurrentTaxonomy,"Taxonomy: ")</h4>
</div>
```

The SightingSearch entity has a property name 'CurrentTaxonomy' and it does contain a value when the page is rendered. However, I cannot get the value to display on the page. All I get is the label text of "Taxonomy: ". I'm guessing I'm overlooking something very basic here.

Comment: `@Html.Label() displays the property name (or the value of the `DisplayNameAttribute`), not the property value. You need `@Html.Display()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to `Taxonomy: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CurrentTaxonomy)`

Comment: Works perfectly. Funny thing is that I'm sure I tried this. I guess not. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. I have experienced similar behavior when making live edits.